# Accessing item attributes in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I am inside a form block in Rails, e.g

```
form_for @widget do |f|
end
```

and am thus able to do things such as f.text_field :attribute etc, how can I also find out what the value of different attributes are in order to carry out some display logic?

For instance, something like

```
form_for @widget do |f|
  f.text_field :some_property
  f.checkbox :active if ????.active
end
```

How can I access the properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
form_for @widget do |f|
  f.text_field :some_property
  f.checkbox :active if @widget.active?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

f.**property**.active

where **property** is any defined method or property of your @widget or the parent of Widget (ActiveRecord usually)