# How to access attributes in a partial of a nested rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms, partial

I want to use the `boolean` attribute `is_white` from my `inner_object` to switch between html code in the the partial `_inner_object_form_fields`. This is my attempt.

```
<%= form_for @outer_object do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :inner_object do |builder| %>
    <%= render :partial => "inner_object_form_fields", :locals =>  { :f => builder } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is **my attempt** of the partial `_inner_object_form_fields`.

```
<% if f.is_white == true %>
  <%= f.label(:name, "White") %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.label(:name, "Black") %>
<% end %>
```

This is the migration file of `InnerObjects`.

```
class InnerObjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :inner_objects do |t|
      t.string "name"
      t.boolean "is_white", :default => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :inner_objects
  end
end
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189156/accessing-item-attributes-in-a-rails-form) but could not retrieve an answer for me.
The question is: How can access the attribut `is_white`? My example does NOT work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<% if f.object.is_white == true %>
```

Seem to remember you could access the object this way (not 100% sure though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is it because `f.is_white` is based on a blank object in the partial? Try

```
<%= form_for @outer_object do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for f.inner_object do |builder| %>
   <%= render :partial => "inner_object_form_fields", :locals =>  { :f => builder } %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That way it's referencing the attached object and any state you've created.

Comment: Sorry Anthony. This does not work for me. I edit my post for clearance.

Answer (score 0):

Even one step further would be to do something like this:

```
 <%= f.fields_for f.inner_object do |builder| %>
   <%= render :partial => "inner_object_form_fields", :locals =>  { :f => builder, :inner_object => builder.object } %>
 <% end %>
```

Then you can do.

```
<% if inner_object.is_white == true %>
```

This way your partials code looks a little cleaner.